# How to run multiple timers one after another with pause in javacript?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, countdowntimer, array-reduce

I need to run multiple timer one after another with pause. Input for timer comes from the array which contains set of times. I did something with reduce method. But could not break early the reduce method.

```js
const times = [5, 4, 5];
function countDown(secs) {
        console.log(secs);
        if (secs === 1) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            return timer;
        }
        secs--;
        var timer = setTimeout(() => countDown(secs), 1000);
}

times.reduce((totalDelay, time) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        countDown(delay);
    }, 1000 * totalDelay);
    const delay = parseInt(time);
    totalDelay += delay;
    return totalDelay;
}, 0);
```

I tried with a boolean to pause and play. The timer is paused by that boolean variable but when I resume two timer is running because of the reduce.

Is there any other way to do this with loop or something?

Comment: This is an X/Y problem. What is the usecase for this?

Comment: I'm working on tabata timer where I have to run timer for set of workouts one after another. For ex, [Prepare, HIIT1, Rest, HIIT2, Rest].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code looks way too complicated. All you have to do is setting the timeout inside a function (without arguments) and use that function as a callback to `setTimeout`.

```js
const times = [5, 4, 5];
function countDown() {
    const secs = times.shift();
    if (typeof secs === 'number') {
        setTimeout(countDown, secs * 1000);
        console.log(`Next timer in ${secs} seconds`);
    } else {
        console.log('Done');
    }
}
countDown();
```

Here I'm removing an element from the start of the `times` array on each iteration. You could also leave the array unchanged and use an index to keep track of the progress.